# sns push notification publish to a single device

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

**This is the code i found on SNS's official site to publish to a topic**

```
String msg = "My text published to SNS topic with email endpoint";
PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(topicArn, msg);
PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
System.out.println("MessageId - " + publishResult.getMessageId());
```

I am developing a chat app on for android using sns(it will also push notifications to the existing ios counterpart of the app)

if i want to publish to a single device directly can i give device's "ApplicationEndPointArn" instead of topicArn

Comment: Publishing from a device to device is not recommended and should not be done. It poses some risks and a customer can swarm another person's device with notifications.

Comment: @RohanDubal so what do you suggest for a chat application??

Comment: If you wanted to write a chat application, you would use your own back-end and either develop your own protocol or develop something based on an existing one like XMPP.  You would use SNS to send off-line notifications from your back-end to the device.

Answer (score 0):

SNS is intended to decouple notification service from application layer.

We could create a topic and add mobile endpoints as subscribers.

When a message is published to the topic all subscribers will get notified.

Apart from this if you would really need single endpoint messaging you could try,

```
PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
publishRequest.setTargetArn(endpointArn);
publishRequest.setMessage("SOME MESSAGE");
snsClient.publish(publishRequest)
```

where endpointArn is a device endpoint.

But make sure that you persist this device endpoint when device is registered in SNS and use the same returned EndpointArn for further communication.